# colorgcc and toolchain prefix

Tags: gcc, cross-compiling

I am cross-compiling with `arm-none-eabi`. I would like to use `colorgcc` to see colorized output of, say, `arm-none-eabi-gcc`.
I've created links in `/usr/local/bin` for prefixed toolchain, as described [here](http://blog2.emptycrate.com/content/using-colorgcc-ubuntu-and-other-linux-distributions).
However, `colorgcc` still invokes `gcc`. Can I do something to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by changing the configuration file colorgccrc. The gcc g++ c++ cc has to be changed according to your cross compiler.

You can find that file in

```
/etc/colorgcc/colorgccrc
```

You can copy it to your home directory  and make the changes you need

```
cp /etc/colorgcc/colorgccrc ~/.colorgccrc
```

Answer (score 1):

### Quick answer

1. Copy `colorgcc.pl` from https://github.com/olibre/colorgcc to your directory `~/bin`
2. Add `~/bin` in the beginning of your `$PATH`
3. In the directory `~/bin`, create a symlink from `arm-none-eabi` to `colorgcc.pl`

   ```
   cd ~/bin
   ln -s colorgcc.pl arm-none-eabi
   ```

### Story

The original [`colorgcc`](https://github.com/colorgcc/colorgcc) (v1.3.2) has not evolved since April 2012 and pull request are ignored.

Then , I have [forked the project](https://github.com/olibre/colorgcc) in 2013 and other contributors worked with me to fix and improve `colorgcc`. The last version is v1.4.4 and we have ideas in the tube to improve it (we will improve it as soon as we have time and motivation).

### Multiple compilers

One major improvement is to look for the compiler executable within `$PATH` instead of hard coded locations within the script.

Using our `colorgcc` you just have to make a symlink from your `arm-none-eabi` to `colorgcc`. You use this `arm-none-eabi` symlink in your terminal. This will call `colorgcc`. And `colorgcc` will look for the other `arm-none-eabi` within the `$PATH`.

For instance, if you have different `gcc` versions installed in different directories. You just have to change the `$PATH` content to select the `gcc` version you want.

There are also other possibilities as the one pointed from [ashwanth selvam](/a/32243621/938111).

### Thanks

This answer has been made possible thanks to [the issue from singalen](https://github.com/olibre/colorgcc/issues/4).